# Creating a struct from array

Tags: go

I have an `Employee struct` which looks like this:

```
type Employee struct {
  firstName string
  lastName  string
  role      string
}
```

I read from an Excel file a row, which has the corresponding columns in the same order.
From the excel file I created an array that holds this data, so the array looks like this:

`[personFirstName, personLastName, personRole]`

And I want to initialize my Employee struct with it.
But I can't figure out how, because I can't iterate over the Employee struct like it's an array.
I thought about doing it manually, like this:

```
e := {
  firstName: array[0],
  lastName: array[1],
  role: array[2],
}
```

But I guess there should be a better way.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Doing it manually is a perfectly good approach. But if you don't want to do that, then you can use `reflect` to range over a struct's fields and set their values.

Comment: ... but [you shouldn't use `reflect`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m23s). Just do it manually.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code in the question. Here's how to use the reflect API to accomplish the goal:

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field to make the fields settable through the reflect API.

```
type Employee struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Role      string
}
```

Create reflect value for an employee. The `&` and `Elem()`
shenanigans are required to get a settable value.

```
var e Employee
v := reflect.ValueOf(&e).Elem()
```

For each field, set the string:

```
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    v.Field(i).SetString(values[i])
}
```

[Run an example on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ptfs3kjlSIl).

Put the code in a function if you need it in more than one place:

```
// setStrings sets the fields of the struct pointed 
// to by ptr to the specified values.
func setStrings(ptr interface{}, values []string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(ptr).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        v.Field(i).SetString(values[i])
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
values := []string{"Monica", "Smith", "Manager"}
var e Employee
setStrings(&e, values)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", e) // prints {FirstName:Monica LastName:Smith Role:Manager}
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rNnlZQiE7jP).